# Order of words with verb - "there is" vs "is there"

Tags: grammar, word-order

I just came across two very similar phrases. They seem to me both grammatically correct and normal, but I cannot quite justify their existence. They are :

1)*...where not only is there only a small cohort that posses the necessary knowledge...*

2)*...where there is only a small cohort that posses the necessary knowledge...*

Is there a name for the reversal of order of the order in the verb "there is"?

Why is it okay and what grammatical rule justifies it? I have looked around and cannot quite find a term naming this phenomenon.

Comment: What the linked answer doesn't mention is that there are a whole load of negative-polarity words and phrases that do this, including _nor_, _neither_, _never_, _nowhere_, _rarely_, _scarcely_, _hardly_, _hardly ever_, and also _only_ followed by expressions of time and place, such as _only sometimes_ and _only in certain places_.

Comment: It's spelt "possess" not "posses", which is the plural of "posse". Although possibly you want "possesses" - cohort might be considered singular or plural.